# 19th century American equivalent of outlandish praise such as "crazy mf!"

Tags: idioms

Is there an 1850's working-class and/or Black equivalent of "crazy Mf!" used as praise?

Comment: "What a jolly good chap!". Or perhaps: "I daresay this man is fabulous!" haha

Comment: @KyranF not really working class, but I get your drift.

Answer (score 1):

"*You're off your chump!*" comes to mind. This was 19th century [British/Australian slang](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/off_one's_chump) to describe someone as crazy. I don't know whether it was used in an ironic sense as a compliment.

"*He'd make a stuffed bird laugh!*" is a Victorian term to describe someone as funny, but again it doesn't convey the same meaning.